# Fast way to build database alteration queries in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

(sorry - the question wasn't originally clear.  I'm not looking for the fastest ways to build insert, delete statements etc, but the fastest way to build queries to alter, for example, tables in the database e.g. adding or removing a column)

So, what's the fastest and best way to build database alteration queries in SQL server?  I'm going down the manual route of writing the SQL as it's given me the best result in the past with the IBM Informix database.  Points to note:

- I've found that using the table designer in management studio is a poor method (in my experience this is too simplistic and GUI driven to be of use, and often requires tables to be completely rebuilt to work well)
- The query designer only allows simple select, update delete etc. queries to be built
- Any recommended tools that make this easier?
- Am I missing something about the SQL management studio that I should know?  Seems to create overly complex SQL for building a table, that's difficult to comprehend and edit

Comment: Use an ORM - nHibernate, Entity Framework or any of the many options open for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Do you write Java, .Net, Python or  code by hand? What's the difference with SQL?

If there are patterns and code generation can be automated, (write and) use a code generator (but that goes for the other languages I listed too).

SQL is a lot more than just SELECT ... WHERE ... or UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE id = value.

Answer (score 0):

for most kinds of scripts, I ask SMS to generate the initial script (create, drop, alter, select, insert, delete, execute, etc), and then tweak to taste. not sure if this is sufficient to your needs, but I find it useful

to generate scripts, Right click an object (table/view/sproc/fn/etc) and expand "Script ".

hope that helps.